# Insert today's date and version number at compile time using typescript

Tags: typescript, date, variables, constants, compile-time

I would like to have a (custom) **version-number** and the **compilation-date** in `javascript` files which have been compiled from `typescript`.

Is there a way to define variables or evaluate date-functions at compile time in TypeScript?

```js
@COMPANY = "myCompanyName";
@VERSION = "2.3.4.5"
// copyright © 2015 - {year(@TODAY)} @COMPANY
//
// version: {@VERSION} 
// release: {@TODAY}`
```

I expect output in .js file like this:

```
// copyright © 2015 - 2019 MyCompanyName
//
// version: 2.3.4.5 
// release: 2019-09-16 10:00:00
```

Comment: TypeScript does not provide this functionality. You need an extra step after your TS compilation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the line is not as well defined, TypeScript is not a build system; it doesn't support any processing like that.

You're better suited using anything else as part of your build process. There are many alternatives; the best one depends on your build workflow.

If you're using Babel (a [common complementary build tool for TS projects](https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/)), you could find that something that suit your needs like [babel-plugin-add-header-comment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-header-comment) or [create one yourself](https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2015/09/13/lets-create-a-babel-plugin/).

You could also [use the compiler library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) instead of the command line to create your files, doing any transformations you wanted.

Or you could create a separate step, after your build process, that does some string/regex replacement on output files - either via JS or via a bash script.